# Curl - Request with wp_remote_get() responds 500, curl_exec responds 200

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, ubuntu-14.04, php-curl

I am getting an odd server **php curl error** in both my local and production servers (`Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11, Apache 2.4.7`).

Basically, a curl request to a remote API returns a status code 500 response, ONLY in `wp_remote_get()`, where it returns status 200 in both `curl_exec()` and a browser request.

**My debug code:**

```
<?php
$url = 'https://yoast.com?edd_action=activate_license&license=my-license-key-here&item_name=WooCommerce+Yoast+SEO&url=https://google.com';

// this return status 200:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';

// this return status 500:
$testResp = wp_remote_get($url);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($testResp, true) . '</pre>';
```

I cannot figure out why it responds 500 for `wp_remote_get()`.  I've tried adjusting args passed to `wp_remote_get()`, but still a **500** with it.

I've also disabled all plugins in debugging.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after a bit of debugging, I believe the issue is the default User-Agent string Wordpress sets in `wp-includes/class-http.php`, set when creating an http request for `wp_remote_get()`.

The option has a filter, but the default is created like so:

```
'user-agent' => apply_filters( 'http_headers_useragent', 'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ),
```

So in my case, the 'user-agent' header value was: `"Wordpress/4.3.1; http://myurl.com"`

When I hook into the filter `http_headers_useragent` and return an empty string, or even a different user-agent string such as: `'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8) AppleWebKit/535.6.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.2 Safari/535.6.2'`, the request will return a successful 200 response.

Not sure if the semicolon is the true culprit, but if I remove it and set the user-agent string to just `"Wordpress/4.3.1"`, the request is successful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems - wp_remote_get was not working while the classic Curl calls were making the calls. Indeed the problem is on 'user agent' . This is my solution based on  "chuuke" findings

```
 $args = array(
            'user-agent'  =>  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8) AppleWebKit/535.6.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.2 Safari/535.6.2',
        ); 
 $data = wp_remote_get($new_url_signed,$args);
```

Thanks