# My HTTP request works with cURL but with wp_remote_get() I get error 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, wordpress, http, curl, get

I am working on a WordPress plugin in which I must retrive product data from ShipHero's API.

When using cURL, I get a sucessful JSON. My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-gateway.shiphero.com/v1/general-api/get-product/?token=$token&sku=$sku");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // Only for debugging locally

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

This is the response I get:

```
    string '
{"Message": "success", "code": "200", "products": {"results": [{"sku": "999999999", "kit_components": [], "warehouses": [{"available": "0", "inventory_bin": "WA7", "inventory_overstock_bin": "", "backorder": "0", "warehouse": "Primary", "on_hand": "0", "allocated": "0"}], "build_kit": 0, "value": "0.00", "kit": 0}]}}
' (length=324)
```

I am supposed to use the helper function wp_remote_get() instead. This is my code:

```
$url = "https://api-gateway.shiphero.com/v1/general-api/
        get-product/?token=$token&sku=$sku";

$response = wp_remote_get($url);

var_dump($response);
```

But what I get is a 403 message (Missing Authentication Token):

```
array (size=6)
  'headers' => 
    object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)[1416]
      protected 'data' => 
        array (size=8)
          'content-type' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
          'content-length' => string '42' (length=2)
          'date' => string 'Tue, 22 Aug 2017 16:11:30 GMT' (length=29)
          'x-amzn-requestid' => string '8f564453e0d-be543534d5-b554385ea7d' (length=36)
          'x-amzn-errortype' => string 'MissingAuthenticationTokenException' (length=35)
          'x-cache' => string 'Error from cloudfront' (length=21)
          'via' => string '1.1 30f76efc52e6ca97f663d61e1f8e27ef.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)' (length=64)
          'x-amz-cf-id' => string 'pmlZLt_c18F4wKiT7eSvfBHCcD-UwxPtP87dALZxIQ==' (length=56)
  'body' => string '{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}' (length=42)
  'response' => 
    array (size=2)
      'code' => int 403
      'message' => string 'Forbidden' (length=9)
```

I have already tried to override the filter 'hhtp_headers_useragent' like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162299/curl-request-with-wp-remote-get-responds-500-curl-exec-responds-200), and nothing changed.

I tried to do some Authorization, with the following code:

```
    $args = array(
                'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ),
                )
            );

$response = wp_remote_request( $url, $args );
```

The username and password I used in this case were respectively the Shop Name and API Secret, given to me by ShipHero in their console (I do not know if that would be the case).

The response is still a 403 code, with the following message:

```
"message":"Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header
```

Why does it work with cURL and not with wp_remote_get?

Comment: By the sounds of the error message; you've forgotten to include the authentication token. Please refer to the documentation of the API used.

Comment: What output do you get if you use `file_get_contents` on your url instead of curl?

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen I did not forget, but it seems it had a typo. Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with cURL and not with wp_remote_get because they were not using the exact same string for $url, and there was a typo in the last one.